# log4j ConsoleAppender printing to console twice even after setting Additivity to false

Tags: java, log4j, executable-jar

I have log4j appenders that print outputs to the console ***once*** when running the program in intellIj
[image]

but ***twice*** when running the program via executable .jar.

[image]

*The actual logs that get written to the log file only appear once which is correct.*

[image]

I define my logger/appenders programmatically in this [code block](https://pastebin.com/4D7S5KHY)

and after everything is done I call

```
rootLogger.setAdditivity(false);
```

but for some reason my classes still output twice to cmdline console when running as a .jar. I call loggers in each class by defining a log variable at the top like so:

```
public class SomeClass {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass .class);
```

and this log variable is used everywhere in the "SomeClass" class.

I've tried setting additivity to false for all the package loggers as well before and after I set their levels...

```
Logger.getLogger("com.company").setAdditivity(false);
Logger.getLogger("com.company.project.database.Admin").setAdditivity(false);
...
```

but when I run the code that way it complains it cannot find the appenders for the class that I'm defining all the log4j stuff in, and nothing gets written to output/log.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with additivity, however additivity is a property of a child, telling log4j not to use the parents:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Repository_Hierarchy_Logger_Additivity.htm
You have set additivity to false for the ultimate parent logger, that will never do anything as root will not be a child of anything.

Try setting the additivity to false of each package logger and hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: I've tried that before by setting all the package loggers additivity's to false after I set their levels, but doing that just gives me a warning when I run that no appenders could be found and then nothing gets output/logged

Comment: In the below, have you tried setting additivity of wheel as false but not car? 
   Logger.getLogger("com.company.project.car").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("com.company.project.car.Wheel").setLevel(Level.INFO);

Comment: tried all that already. one day the problem simply vanished. it now no longer double prints to cmd line console (although now it double prints in intelliJ console) i guess we'll chalk it up to the mysteries of the universe.